# choosing between different objects in JSON-schema

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm creating a schema for receipts and want to have a master schema for the core concepts with a variety of different detail objects for specialized receipt types (e.g. itemized hotel receipts, etc.) My current implementation is leveraging the `oneOf` mechanism in JSON-schema

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "Receipt",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        ...
        "amount": { "type": "number" },
        "detail": {
            "type": "object",
            "oneOf": [
                { "$ref": "general-detail.schema.json" },
                { "$ref": "hotel-detail.schema.json" },
                ...
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that when I validate (using tv4), it appears that all of the schemas specified in `oneOf` are being checked, and are in fact, returning errors. I can minimize this effect by getting rid of the `detail` property, moving `oneOf` to the schema-level (e.g. outside of `properties`) and then creating root property names in each of the sub-schemas. However, even in that case, I get a "Missing required property: generalDetail" in the event that there's an error when I'm validating a hotel receipt type.

So 2 questions:

- is it even possible to use a generic `detail` property like I'm currently doing and not have the validator completely validate each sub-schema in the `oneOf` structure (e.g. am I using `oneOf` wrongly)?
- if it is not possible, I would be more than fine simply having a set of 'typed' detail properties (like 'generalDetail', 'hotelDetail', etc.) - but is there a way to specify that they are a group and that only one of them should exist in the document being validated?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

1. It is usually better using anyOf - it is very rarely when you need oneOf. The latter will alway validate all schemas, the former will most likely exit at the first that passes.
2. You may look at some other validators. tv4 has many deviations from the standard and also is very slow. https://github.com/ebdrup/json-schema-benchmark

Answer (score 0):

All of the schemas in `oneOf` need to be validated in order for the validator to ensure that only one of the schemas pass.  If none pass or more than one pass, the validator needs to tell you the validation results of each schema in order for you to determine how to fix the error.

So, just because the validator is telling you why each of the schemas are failing doesn't mean that it expects all of those schemas to pass.